# 2022 Election ended - insufficient candidates - What are your thoughts about moderation and Tor SE?

Tags: discussion, election

The recent election for moderators here on Tor [ended early due to there being insufficient candidates](https://tor.stackexchange.com/election/4) for the election to continue to the voting phase. While we needed at least four candidates, we had only the two existing moderators stepping up to fill these roles.

Since we had initially planned to count this as a pro-tem election should there not be enough candidates, this isn't a problem for you all - fortunately, there are few flags raised and not a lot of content that needs moderation and the existing mods are willing to stay on. We're grateful for their continued work!

What we want to do is ensure that this community has enough support to stay clean and full of high-quality content. As long as there are at least two mods and they don't feel overburdened by the workload, that's fine - though we would generally prefer at least three moderators.

In that vein - and as part of our general interest in understanding the motivations of the community members on these sites - I'm curious if anyone would like to talk about their reasons for or against nominating as a moderator here. We need to understand that if we're going to ensure that our sites have longevity and can be here for years to come.

Tor is a big part of the internet and is used by millions of people daily - and yet this site is small and relatively low-activity. Are there ways to make this site more useful and accessible to those users - or are there other places for information about Tor that make SE an unlikely place to ask?

Considering this - as a user or even moderator of this site - **What are your thoughts about moderation here and the future of Tor Stack Exchange?**.

Comment: I'll be honest... I love Tor, but Tor.SE seems to be seriously lacking in high-quality questions and answers, and I believe it needs moderators that can better curate the content and encourage intelligent participation. It was initially created by Tor Project as their "official" support community, but right now it's pretty much exclusively "help me thing don't work" or "how do I do this thing tangentially related to Tor?".